# Why does this MakeFile rule have two colons?

Tags: gcc, makefile

```
$(EXEX) : main% : $(OBJS) pp%.o
    gcc $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

I am just trying to understand the above.
As I understand it, everything in EXEX are targets which will be built using the following pattern.

main, OBJS and pp.o are prerequisites for things in EXEX.
The second line will compile $^(meaning all the prereqs) using gcc with all the flags in FLAGS as object files in order to build $@ which is the contents of EXEX. There need to be rules to build all those -o's.

My question is why are there two colons? Is this two rules?
Does main% mean = main with any file ending?
Why do we need the % in pp%.o, what does it mean in this case? It seems to have many many purposes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not the case.

Comment: This is form a makefile from a past school assignment. It works. I'm just trying to deconstruct it to understand it fully.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html).  See the linked GNU make documentation.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind answering this part: Does main% mean = main with any file ending? Why do we need the % in pp%.o?

Comment: The docs do explain it, better than I can here in a comment.  Yes, `main%` means `main` plus some suffix.  The `%` in `pp%.o` means that the prerequisite is based on the suffix.  So if the target is `mainfoo` then the prerequisite is `ppfoo.o`.  If the target is `mainbar` then the prerequisite is `ppbar.o`.